# SQL for returning rows against only one type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was not sure what to put in the title. I have a 
`SCHOOL` table, with:

```
id, 
name,
type_id
```

columns.

A `SCHOOL_STUDENT` table with:

```
school_id,
student_id
```

columns 

 and a `SCHOOL_TYPE` table with

```
id, 
name
```

columns.

Students can be enrolled **in more than one schools**. A school can be of **only one type**. Given a student I want to check if he/she is enrolled in schools with only type(high shcool), and no other schools. I want to check if the student is enrolled in schools with only type(high shcool), and no other schools. If a student is enrolled in two schools and one of them is a high school and one of them is a technology school then I want some negative indication. If both of those schools are high school , i want positive indication. Let's suppose SCHOOL_TYPE has a row with id:3 and name:"high school".

SAMPLE DATA:

**SCHOOL table**
id:name:type_id

```
1:'abc school':3
2:'xyz school':4
3:'HEH school':3
```

**SCHOOL_TYPE table**
id:name

```
1:'junior school'
2:'tech school'
3:'High school'
```

**SCHOOL_STUDENT table:**
school_id:student_id

```
1,123
3,123
2, 56
3, 56
```

See studentID:123 is enrolled in two schools, with id:1 and id:3. And both of those schools are of type:3, that means I want a success result. If the same student is enrolled in more than one school and those schools belong to other types as well (other than typeID:3) then I want a failure.

Expected output for studentID:123 is YES and for studentID:56 is NO because he is enrolled in two schools and one of them is not a high school.

I am trying this but I know it lacks something but what it lacks, I don't seem to work it out.

```
select
    bc.customer_id, bt.name, count(bt.[name])
from
    school_type st 
    join school s on s.type_id = st.id
    join school_student ss on ss.school_id = s.id
where 
    ss.student_id = 1234
group by 
    ss.student_id, st.name
```

May be use HAVING? or CASE?

**QUESTION UPDATED:**

Comment: sample data and expected result is helpfull

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results. Also, I see that you have a typo in the select clause with alias names.

Comment: sample data provided

Comment: What do you mean success and failure? What output should be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery with `not exists`

```
select
    ss.student_id, st.name, count(bt.[name])
from
    school_type st join school s on s.type_id = st.id
    join school_student ss on ss.school_id = s.id
where 
    ss.student_id = 1234 and not exists (select 1 from school s1 where ss.school_id = s1.id and s1.type_id<>3)
group by 
    ss.student_id, st.name
```

Comment: It will exclude the remaining schools and schools types from the result set but thats not what I want.

Comment: @user1451111, could you please add your expected output in table format

Comment: expected output added